# What does || mean in pseudocode?

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

I have problem understanding the symbol ||. It is used in the pseudocode for Byzantine implementation.

```
:= sign(self, bonrr || self || WRITE || was || v);
```

Comment: You need to give the link to the source where you have read this.

Comment: There is no "standard" pseudocode. *Pseudo*code is, as the name suggests, something that people invent themselves. It might mean a logical "*or*". But normally the paper itself will make it clear (or certain notation that is popular in the field in which the paper is written).

Comment: Refer to the lexical conventions for the source; they should be documented at the start of the book, paper, or web site.  A single bar within brackets, such as `[ bonrr | self | ... ]` has long been used to denote that exactly *one* of the list elements must be supplied.  Does something close to that work in your context?

Answer (score 0):

It's OR sign. If at least one of them(bonrr, self, WRITE, was, v) is TRUE, then (bonrr || self || WRITE || was || v) will be TRUE. You might have heard of logical operators like AND, OR etc.

Comment: It does not necessarily mean that in this context, and most likely doesn't. There is no universal programming syntax, and even less so for pseudocode.